# A pool of child processes

Tags: c, multiprocessing, signals, fork, child-process

I have a fixed number of child processes that I can create to handle some tasks.
I was wondering if there was a way in C to create all of them at the start of the program (basically generating a pool of processes), use one of them for the task at hand instead of creating another, and then putting it back to the pool.

I just started learning about fork() and signals in general so I can imagine such a thing existing, but do not know how to implement it in C, can you guys help me with some code examples or tell me what signals/functions should I look into to solve my problem?

P.s. My idea would be creating all of them at the start, put all of them to sleep, and then send a signal to wake the one that I need, make it do my bidding(dunno with what condition though)  and then put it back to sleep again.

P.p.s.
Unfortunately I can't use threads

Comment: You likely want threads, not processes.  Threads share the same address space, so that you can easily communicate between them without using pipes or shared memory, etc.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/  If you really did intend to fork() off child processes: https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your reply, but I can't use any thread in this program (we still haven't done them) I'm gonna edit my post to include this little detail. What do you think of my idea, is it feasible?

Comment: @MIke I read the link but it was just about how the fork() works, it didn't really help me that much with my idea, thanks anyway :)

Comment: There's no end to the information out there about fork().  Stevens's old books, like UNIX Network Programming are great resources.  Or just google around for something like "fork sleep kill".  Unfortunately, there aren't any easy answers here, just a lot to learn about how process management works.